# Signing data using a p12 / pfx file in .Net - An internal certificate chaining error has occurred

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, x509, x509certificate2

I'm trying to port some java code to C# and I'm having an issue when it comes to signing the data. The error I receieve is "**An internal certificate chaining error has occurred.**"

The code runs sucessfully in java on my machine but not in C#.

Below is my C# code which throws the exception on ComputeSignature:

```
 //Import the certificate
        var certificate2Collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificate2Collection.Import(certificateFilePath, "**password**", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);

        //Only one cert in pks file
        var cert2 = certificate2Collection[0];

        //create data to be signed
        var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " 00:00:00";
        var modifiedTimestamp = userName + "|" + time;
        var dataToSign = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(modifiedTimestamp);

        var content = new ContentInfo(dataToSign);
        var signedMessage = new SignedCms(content);

        var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(cert2);
        signedMessage.**ComputeSignature**(cmsSigner);

        byte[] signedBytes = signedMessage.Encode();

        string signedData = Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);
```

Here is the java code that works:

```
        final String time = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new java.util.Date());

    final String timestamp = time + " 00:00:00";

    // Create the data to be signed
    final String modifiedTimestamp = userName + "|" + timestamp;
    final byte[] ba = modifiedTimestamp.getBytes();

    final byte[] signedData; 

    final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(certificateStoreType);

    ks.load(certificateStream, certificatePassword);

    // Get the certificate from the keystore using the alias            
    final X509Certificate inCert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(certificateAlias == null ? userName : certificateAlias);

    // Get the private key using the alias and the password            
    final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(keyAlias == null ? userName : keyAlias, certificatePassword);

    // Get the algorithm name from the certificate            
    final String issuerSigAlg = inCert.getSigAlgName();

    // Get the signature for the specified algorithm            
    final Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(issuerSigAlg);

    // Sign the message           
    sig.initSign(privateKey);            
    sig.update(ba);            
    signedData = sig.sign();
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

**EDIT**
I now have this working but my code has had to change significantly. I've auto converted the java code to see what gets generated. The result is below, however this does make certain assumptions about the Crypto Algo being used.:-

```
var buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int) fs.Length);
            var certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(buffer, certificatePassword);

            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " 00:00:00";
            string modifiedTs = userName + "|" + timestamp;

            var cryptoKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            var formatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(cryptoKey);
            formatter.SetKey(certificate2.PrivateKey);
            formatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(modifiedTs);
            var rgbBytes = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(bytes);
            string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(formatter.CreateSignature(rgbBytes));
```

Comment: That's not an edit, that's an answer. Post it below and accept it (after a while).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first certificate (which you access in C#) is not the one you expect - not an end-entity certificate with a private key, but intermediate or root CA. Consequently signer class can't use it for signing. The simplest approach to check if the assumption is correct is to try with all certificates in collection and see if anyone of them works.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your help. Actually there is only one certificate in the file. Any other ideas?